# Are "walk" and "run" only for humans

Tags: verbs

I'd like to know if verbs *walk* and *run* are only used for humans. I think that *walk* is, but not sure about *run*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Walk* and *run* can be used for people, animals and even some non-human objects.

For example:

> The robot is *walking*

It can also be used for animals as well:

> The dog is *running* ahead of me
>
> The cat is *walking* very slowly

The most common use is for humans but it can also be used for animals and some non-human object.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say 'run' can be used for anything with legs, including robots.
The verb also is used in the sense of "run away", "escape". In that case, it might even apply to creatures without legs occasionally.
Idiom: "You can run, but you can't hide!"

'walk' is most commonly used with things that have 2 legs, but sometimes it is also applicable to a slow movement of 4-legged creatures.